# Convert SQL Server query to MS Access 2003

Tags: sql-server

Here is SQL Server query that needs to be converted to MS Access 2003:

```
select  distinct u.ssn,u.[name],d.deptname,convert(varchar(12),c.checktime,103)Date,
 case  when convert(varchar(8),min(checktime),8)  between(select convert(varchar(8),checkintime1,8)startin
    from schclass_bak where schname like'Morning')and(select convert(varchar(8),checkintime2,8)endin
    from schclass_bak where schname like'Morning')
    then convert(varchar(8),min(checktime),8) else '0' end MOIN,
isnull(( select  max(convert(varchar(8),(checktime),8)) 
 from checkinOut g
 where (convert(varchar(8),(checktime),8))  between (select convert(varchar(8),checkouttime1,8)startOut
from schclass_bak where schname like'Morning') and (select convert(varchar(8),checkouttime2,8)endout
from schclass_bak where schname like'Morning') and g.USERID=u.userid and convert(varchar(12),g.checktime,103)=convert(varchar(12),c.checktime,103) ),'12:00')Mout,

case  when convert(varchar(8),max(checktime),8)  between(select convert(varchar(8),checkintime1,8)startin
    from schclass_bak where schname like'Afternoon')and(select convert(varchar(8),checkintime2,8)endin
    from schclass_bak where schname like'Afternoon')
    then convert(varchar(8),max(checktime),8) else '0' end AIN,
case when convert(varchar(8),max(checktime),8)  between(select convert(varchar(8),checkouttime1,8)startOut
    from schclass_bak where schname like'Afternoon')and(select convert(varchar(8),checkouttime2,8)endout
    from schclass_bak where schname like'Afternoon')
then convert(varchar(8),max(checktime),8) else '17:30' end AOUT

from checkinOut c inner join userinfo u on c.userid=u.userid
inner join departments d on u.defaultdeptid=d.deptid
where cast(convert(varchar(12),c.checktime)as smalldatetime)between '20170401' and '20170425' and u.ssn='50'
  group by  convert(varchar(12),c.checktime,103) ,u.ssn,u.[name],d.deptname,u.USERID
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried converting it yourself? What was the problems you ran into?

Comment: yes i tried but i got too many errors , ms access not support case and between operator

Comment: This query makes me want to take out my eyeballs and pop them. It horrible to read and the same query is in there over and over and over. This needs to be rewritten in a way that makes sense first. You have a number of logical issues in here too. Things like convert datetime to a string and then doing range comparisons.

Comment: show the code you tried as well, and report the errors you got. Otherwise you're just asking us to write the whole thing for you, which isn't really the purpose of this site

Comment: also Sean is right, there's no reason to deal with dates and times as strings, there are plenty of date functions both in SQL Server and Access which would be much easier to use. The way you've got it is likely very brittle and is very difficult to understand for another programmer (without a lot of comments, anyway).

Comment: I also like the like statements with no wildcards. Classic!

Comment: this query has a problem when i execute the column AIN is always 0

Answer (score 1):

I changed your formatting a little, but mostly, I think I got it right.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.ssn,u.[name],d.deptname,Format(c.checktime,"dd/mm/yyyy") as [Date],
 iif( Format(min(checktime),"h:nn:ss") between (select Format(checkintime1,"h:nn:ss") as startin
    from schclass_bak where schname like 'Morning')and(select Format(checkintime2,"h:nn:ss") as endin
    from schclass_bak where schname like 'Morning')
    , Format(min(checktime),"h:nn:ss") 
    , '0') MOIN,
 isnull(( select  max(Format(checktime,"h:nn:ss")) 
    from checkinOut g where (Format(checktime,"h:nn:ss")  between (select Format(checkouttime1,"h:nn:ss") as startOut
    from schclass_bak where schname like 'Morning') and (select Format(checkouttime2,"h:nn:ss") as endout
    from schclass_bak where schname like 'Morning') and g.USERID=u.userid and Format(g.checktime,"dd/mm/yyyy")=Format(c.checktime,"dd/mm/yyyy") ),'12:00')Mout,
 iif( Format(max(checktime),"h:nn:ss")  between(select Format(checkintime1,"h:nn:ss") as startin
    from schclass_bak where schname like 'Afternoon') and (select Format(checkintime2,"h:nn:ss") as endin
    from schclass_bak where schname like 'Afternoon')
    , Format(max(checktime),"h:nn:ss") 
    , '0') AIN,
 iif( Format(max(checktime),"h:nn:ss") between(select Format(checkouttime1,"h:nn:ss") as startOut
    from schclass_bak where schname like 'Afternoon')and(select Format(checkouttime2,"h:nn:ss") as endout
    from schclass_bak where schname like 'Afternoon')
    , Format(max(checktime),"h:nn:ss") 
    , '17:30') AOUT

FROM checkinOut c inner join userinfo u on c.userid=u.userid
 INNER JOIN departments d on u.defaultdeptid=d.deptid
WHERE Format(c.checktime, "yyyymmdd") between '20170401' and '20170425' and u.ssn='50'
GROUP BY  Format(c.checktime,"dd/mm/yyyy"), u.ssn, u.[name], d.deptname, u.USERID
```

Btw, Here are a few SQL Server to MS Access conversion tips:

- CASE WHEN THEN END -> iif(condition, true part, false part)
- field aliasing requires the keyword "As". Example: select max(dollars) as maxdollars
- To convert a date to a varchar (with formatting): Format(field, "mask")

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.ssn, u.name, Format(c.checktime,"dd/mm/yyyy") AS [Date], IIf(Format(Min(checktime),"h:nn:ss") Between (select Format(checkintime1,"h:nn:ss") as startin     from schclass where schname like 'Morning') And (select Format(checkintime2,"h:nn:ss") as endin     from schclass where schname like 'Morning'),Format(Min(checktime),"h:nn:ss"),'0') AS MOIN, IIf((select  max(Format(checktime,"h:nn:ss"))      from checkinOut g where Format(checktime,"h:nn:ss")  between (select Format(checkouttime1,"h:nn:ss") as startOut     from schclass  where schname like 'Morning') and (select Format(checkouttime2,"h:nn:ss") as endout     from schclass  where schname like 'Morning') and g.USERID=u.userid and Format(g.checktime,"dd/mm/yyyy")=Format(c.checktime,"dd/mm/yyyy")),(select  max(Format(checktime,"h:nn:ss"))      from checkinOut g where Format(checktime,"h:nn:ss")  between (select Format(checkouttime1,"h:nn:ss") as startOut     from schclass  where schname like 'Morning') and (select Format(checkouttime2,"h:nn:ss") as endout     from schclass  where schname like 'Morning') and g.USERID=u.userid and Format(g.checktime,"dd/mm/yyyy")=Format(c.checktime,"dd/mm/yyyy")),'12:00') AS Mout, IIf(Format(Max(checktime),"h:nn:ss") Between (select Format(checkintime1,"h:nn:ss") as startin     from schclass where schname like 'Afternoon') And (select Format(checkintime2,"h:nn:ss") as endin     from schclass where schname like 'Afternoon'),Format(Max(checktime),"h:nn:ss"),'0') AS AIN, IIf(Format(Max(checktime),"h:nn:ss") Between (select Format(checkouttime1,"h:nn:ss") as startOut     from schclass where schname like 'Afternoon') And (select Format(checkouttime2,"h:nn:ss") as endout     from schclass where schname like 'Afternoon'),Format(Max(checktime),"h:nn:ss"),'17:30') AS AOUT
FROM checkinOut AS c INNER JOIN userinfo AS u ON c.userid = u.userid
WHERE (((Format([c].[checktime],"yyyymmdd")) Between [dt] And [edate]) AND ((u.ssn) Like [idss]))
GROUP BY u.ssn, u.name, Format(c.checktime,"dd/mm/yyyy"), u.USERID;
```

Comment: I've added basic code formatting, but this is still unreadable and also contains no explanation whatsoever of what has been changed, or why. Considering there's quite a lot of code, it would be worth doing.